# tkinter & PIL: removing image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write simple app that would display poster of random movie after button is pressed.
Problem: I don't know how to remove one image before displaying next one (so they don't stack on each other, like here: [image]).

My shortened code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


mlist = ['resized.jpg', 'cat.jpg']
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, padding='5')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        self.create_button()
        self.name = ttk.Label()
        self.image = ttk.Label()

    def create_button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self,
                             text="Press me",
                             width=12,
                             command=lambda: self.display()
                             ).grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2, pady=10,  sticky=N)

    def display(self):
        self.name.destroy()
        k = random.randrange(0, 2)
        self.name = ttk.Label(self, font=(None, 16), text=mlist[k])
        self.image = Image.open(mlist[k])
        poster = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        display = ttk.Label(self, image=poster)
        display.my_image = poster

        display.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=3)
        self.name.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=3)


root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("550x575")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I believe, I should apply something similar to 'self.name.destroy()' on 'self.image'. However  doesn't have such method... so how to solve it?

Comment: You would have more control over your images by using a `canvas` widget. It includes a method to remove the image displayed.

Comment: Your code seems to work OK when I try it. Initially there's no image, after pressing the button it displays `resized.jpg`, and then after another button press it shows `cat.jpg`. One—apparently unrelated—potential problem I see in your code is that you assign the result of calling the `ttk.Button.grid()` method to `self.button`. The `grid()` method returns `None`.